# Accessing remote service methods in both binded service

Tags: android, ipc, android-service, aidl

I have two services A and B. If we want to access some methods of service B in service A we have to create a ServiceConnection class and inside service A we have to create Stub and implements the methods.

But I also want to access the methods of service A from service B. For trial I created one more aidl connection and implemented ServiceConnection it works fine, is it the only way OR we can use the **existing** serviceconnection and implement this functionality by other way?

Comment: Are you required to support cross-process "talk"? If you're running in the same process you really don't need to bother with AIDL unless you absolutely feel like it.

Comment: Yes both services are in diff process.

Comment: @BrijeshMasrani - Did this solution help you?  Remember AIDL is expensive.  Although no really used in "Android" development, sockets would be an easy way to create a two way communication line.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this is the only way AIDL works from my experience.  You could always create a custom callback that could be passed into service B from service A, then when B would like to send back to A it could trigger the callback.  There is also the option of passing intents back and forth or communication through a socket.  Just make sure you are blocking on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Services can certainly have callback interfaces (i.e. so services can call methods in clients).

Suggest you refer to [the RemoteService example in the SDK](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.html).